# System.Data.SqlClient used in System.Data?

Tags: .net, apache, c#-3.0, mono

I have had that weird error this afternoon... I cannot figure out why System.Data could rely on System.Data.SqlClient.

This happens in Mono under Linux, and I do not rely on SQL Server at all, by the way...

Oh! It says that it's only a warning but the compiler stops doing it job anyway.

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: Error compiling a
>   resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and
>   modify it to fix this error.
>
> Compiler Error Message: : **
>   (/usr/local/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:8658):
>   WARNING **: The class
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder could
>   not be loaded, used in System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   ~/Global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder lives in System.Data.dll.  I am surprised Mono hasn't implemented this simple enum, but apparently it hasn't:

http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=2.0&profile=2.0&assembly=System.Data

You (or some auto-generated code) must be referencing it, perhaps in Global.asax.

Comment: I have included MvcContrib and MvcContrib.FluentHtml in my project. Before that I had no compilation error.

Comment: Closer investigation shows that SortOrder is used several times in MVCContrib\UI\Grid\Sortable